# Create Blank Field in Peoplesoft Query Manager

Tags: sql, oracle, peoplesoft, peoplesoft-query

I want to generate an output with blank/empty column with a "Select" query in oracle. I'm able to achieve this with below sql query:

```
SELECT CustomerName AS Customer, "" AS Contact 
FROM Customers;
```

How is this blank field ('' as Contact) created Oracle Peoplesoft Query Manager?  I can only create fields from a table.

Comment: I just found the solution.....In Expressions, click on Add Expressions.  Type '' (two single quotes) and click OK.  Click on Use as Field.  Click on Edit and type the name of the field in the Heading Text.  Click on OK

Comment: sounds, good except PeopleSoft only allows date fields and long text fields to be null, so you might need to make it wrap your quotes around 1 blank space instead of nothing.